# Footer with absolute positioned divs of varying heights?

Tags: css, html, position, footer, absolute

I'm trying to turn this design ( http://revivelab.com/demo_sites/bookthatcondo/ ) into a wordpress theme, and you'll notice the footer has 'position:absolute;bottom:0;top:1500px;' on it. The 1500px is what I need to change because I don't want to have to specify a top-position that is unique to every single page. The divs above it are absolute so they can be layered for the wave/slider effect.

Does anyone have any advice or tips on how to achieve this? Do I *have* to use absolute positioning for the rest of the site to achieve those 'layers'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so I found a way to do this... it might be a little confusing, but it works:

You need to find the div with the id `canvas`. wrap everything inside that div (not the div itself) with a new div given a new id (ie canvas2). then you should have something looking like this:

```
<div id="canvas">
   <div id="canvas2">
     <!-- all the other code here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

after you have that, you need to take your ENTIRE footer and place it inside the `<div id="canvas">` what you should have now should look like

```
<div id="canvas">
   <div id="canvas2">
     <!-- all the other code here -->
   </div>
  <div style="<!--Your footer styles here -->">
   <!-- footer content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

after you do that, your website will look pretty messed up. but thats because we need to move a few of the css attributes.

right now your footer is using `inline styling` that looks like this:

`style="width:100%;height:269px; background-image:url(img/footer_Wave.png); background-position:50% 0%; background-repeat:no-repeat; position:absolute;bottom:0;top:1500px;"`

If you want to continue using the inline styling, just change it to this:
`style="width:100%;height:269px; background-image:url(img/footer_Wave.png); background-position:50% 0%; background-repeat:no-repeat; margin-top:50px"`

Next, your `#canvas` div has these styles applied:

```
#canvas {
 width: 1024px; 
 height: 1000px; 
 position: absolute; 
 z-index: 5000; 
 left: 50%; 
 margin-left: -512px;
}
```

change that to this:

```
#canvas {
 width: 100%; 
 position: absolute; 
 z-index: 5000;
}
```

Last, give `#canvas2` these styles:

```
#canvas2 {
 width: 1024px; 
 margin:auto;
}
```

That should fix it for each page.. It looks like alot of changes, but its not much really at all. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH, JCBiggar! That worked perfectly! I hate to bother, but can you try to explain why it fixed it? I'm VERY grateful it's fixed but I'd like to learn what I did "wrong" for next time, if you don't mind =)

Comment: It wont let me post too much here. I tried pasting it in two comments, but it will only let me post 1 comment at a time. Sorry!

Comment: Here I just posted it a jsfiddle! haha! here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/g3Avj/2/

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't have to specify how long you want the page in order to have a footer stick to the bottom.

Try [Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) instead.  It uses a negative `margin-top` so that all you have to know is your footer height, not the height of the actual page.  It can really help if you have a lot of different page heights.

Comment: Does Sticky Footer work with absolute divs, though? It just seems to make the footer pop up and 'under' the absolute divs